# JBOSS Standalone XML Override "activation-config-property" for inbound MQ communication?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, message-driven-bean

We are using JBOSS EAP 6.4 with WMQ adapter. We have a MDB whose activation config properties are configured inside "ejb-jar.xml". Application is already deployed into the production and we need to override/add new activation config property. We can not afford to modify ejb-jar.xml and create new release archive.

Is it possible to override existing "activation-config-property" or add new "activation-config-property" using standalone deployment descriptor?

I referred to similar SO threads (mentioned below). But nothing was helpful:

[Change Activation-Config-Property on deployment via JBoss CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212788/change-activation-config-property-on-deployment-via-jboss-cli)

[Changing Activation Config of Topic reading MDB at deploy time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858781/changing-activation-config-of-topic-reading-mdb-at-deploy-time)

[MDB set ActivationConfig dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921341/mdb-set-activationconfig-dynamically)

Please let me know if you have any idea on to override these activation config properties using standalone descriptor or using JBOSS CLI.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A deployment overlay should help in your situation:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/deployment_descriptor_overrides